# How to read schematic for PCBs

Tags: pcb, schematics

How do I learn to read a schematic and understand the function and how the circuit work? Where can I find information about the schematic symbol and how it work and why some circuits look the way the do? I know what a resistor or a capacitor do, but I would like to know why they are located and which signals I should prioritize when doing the layout.

Comment: In the old days we used to subscribe to electronics magazines, study the schematics, the explanatory text and the PCB layouts. We were also able to reverse-engineer circuits and create the schematics. Life was simpler then as you could see the components with the naked eye, part numbers were stamped on them and there were few programmed devices.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, the question (as posed) is too broad; not knowing the type of circuit in advance, we would have to recommend a comprehensive engineering curriculum starting from math/circuit analysis all the way to specific types of design. However, if you can share (with attribution) a *specific* schematic and specific questions about its operation, we would be happy to explain how it works and what kinds of classes/resources would cover its important theory.

Comment: The best way is to learn a simulation cum PCB design software like proteus. I myself learnt this way. I drew simple circuits like one LED with resistor and one microcontroller. Then by clicking 'ARES' in proteus, the schematic was converted to PCB layout. I had to draw the traces and avoid errors. Here are some names of  online PCB designing software that you can use : https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2022/11/top-online-software-used-for-pcb-designing.html

Comment: @nanofarad, get admission in an electrical engineering degree would be a more suitable answer here. :-D

Comment: @pakieng A degree is an option, but it's not an option for everyone due to cost, time, etc. There's a large number of great self-study programs that can be fairly effective with the right commitment on the part of the student, and although they won't provide the same level of feedback or formal degree they are still fairly instructive.

Comment: @nanofarad it's easy to find the "self-study programs" useful once you have the foundation built by a degree. I haven't seen a single EE enthusiast who has a good functional knowledge of circuit analysis and design without having an EE degree but maybe at least a few dozen people with degrees who I would say are good with what they do in EE. As an example, can you say the ratio of people you know are good electric circuit analyzers or designers without a degree to the ones with a degree? You can use you own definitions of "good", "circuit analysis", and "circuit design".

Comment: @pakieng I've had the pleasure of working with a number of absolutely brilliant people that didn't take a traditional degree path, and self studied instead. A subset of them are so skilled with so much practical experience that I'd trust them over my own theoretical knowledge in their respective specialties. I myself have done both parts, self study first, and then an EE degree when my own situation allowed me to - and even then, I'm working in a different field where my knowledge is more self study and barely touched on in my degree ..

Comment: ...that isn't to say that self study is easy, or I guarantee everyone success in it, but it's certainly possible with the right motivation. And I'm remiss to count people or calculate ratios, because by simply being in a social/professional network at an engineering school, I already know that my own observation of the people around me is biased toward those in a formal degree program. To be clear, when I say self study programs, I mean quality resources like MIT OCW, not random websites of unknown quality.

Comment: @nanofarad Thanks. This sums it up. "I already know that my own observation of the people around me is biased toward those in a formal degree program." I would suppose it's the same for most of the people.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I learn to read a schematic and understand the function and how the circuit work?

Practice and experience. Read books, take lectures and watch YouTube videos. Like people, every circuit is different. But circuits have similarities, just like some people have similar personalities. You should read enough explanations about circuits that when you see an arbitrary circuit, it reminds you of a similar circuit that you had seen in a book or in a lecture, that you know how works. Then you extend the knowledge of the familiar circuit to the one that you have at hand.

> Where can I find information about the schematic symbol and how it work and why some circuits look the way the do?

Circuits look like the way they look like because some person was trying to solve some problem when they were designing the circuit, and that circuit was what they came up with, in the situation they had. The only place where you can find information about the schematic symbol is where it came from, e.g. datasheets, application notes, YouTube videos, blog websites etc. If you can't trace it to a source you have to use your prior knowledge and experience to try to guess. And with enough experience, you can get very good at that. It is best to ask for help about what you don't understand.

> I know what a resistor or a capacitor do, but I would like to know why they are located and which signals I should prioritize when doing the layout.

Experience.

1. Be knowledgeable about how the circuit works by reading or watching explanations of how similar circuits work. Note that this may be a months or years long process depending on how well you want to understand.
2. See how other people have approached the situation.
3. Attempt it yourself and ask for feedback.

With enough experience and feedback, you will be able to do it all alone.

Answer (score 0):

In a well-drawn circuit, high supply voltages should be at the top, and low ones at the bottom.

Signals go from left to right (except feedback paths that have to go the other way).  So start on the left of the diagram, looking at the inputs, then trace how the signals work through to the right.